# Element navigation must be declared

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to do a bottom navigation menu, I made a new folder under "res" called "nav" and then in here I put this code but it doesn't work it gives me this error at the beginning

Error: Element navigation must be declared

```
public class HomeFragment extends AppCompatActivity {
private CardView btn_home;
private ActivityMainBinding binding;

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View  view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    return view.getRootView();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
    btn_home = findViewById(R.id.trovamico);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_chat, R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_forum).build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.navView, navController);
}



    btn_home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeFragment.this, TrovamicoActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Try changing your folder name from "nav" to "navigation".

Comment: It works but in the 3 fragments it gives me problems in name label and layout. For example in the second it gives me these errors: Unresolved class 'DashboardFragment', Cannot resolve symbol '@ string / title_dashboard', Cannot resolve symbol '@ layout / fragment_dashboard'. What should I put in these 3 fragments? the code i got it up Yt for this doesn't work right away in my code

Comment: I should do 3 buttons, one to go to chat, one for home and one for forum

Comment: Have you created the classes for the fragments? If yes, then add your package name before the class name in the name field. For example: add "com.your.package.DashboardFragment" to the name field. Next check if '@string/title_dashboard' has been declared in the "strings.xml' file. And as for the layout file, check if it has been created in the "layout" folder.

Comment: "strings.xml" file where can I find it?

Comment: It will be inside the "values" folder.

Comment: Edited question with strings.xml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244303/discussion-between-chandresh-parmar-and-pritumbas).